# How to pass serialized form data to datatables?

Tags: jquery, forms, datatables

I use datatables with server-side handler. Major code:

```
$("#dt-flats-build").dataTable({
   processing: true,
   serverSide: true,
   ajax: {
                url: "/api.json",
                data: $('form#filter').serialize()
   },
   });
```

and I have a form with filter. I pass form data to the api.json as addential params.

So, I can pass only fields one by one, but not all fields from form. 
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So why not serialize form object ? Suppose myform is form object then use $(myform).serialize()

Comment: as you may see I do it. form#filter is form. And I serialize it by using jquery, but does not see form's fields in ajax request.

Comment: Try adding - type: "POST", inside ajax:{}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, that I find out solution:

```
ajax: {
  url: "/api.json",
  data: function ( d ) {
  d.form = $('form#filter').serializeArray();
  }
 }
```

form puts in var "form"

Answer (score 1):

Check out here - https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/post.html

> By default, the Ajax request that DataTables makes to obtain server-side processing data is an HTTP GET request. However, there are times when you might wish to use POST. This is very easily done by using the type option of the ajax initialisation option.

Use -

```
"ajax": {
        url: "/api.json",
        "type": "POST",
        data: $('form#filter').serialize()
    },
```

Comment: This method will not work.  I've tried it.  It will always return the original data when the page was loaded and it won't pull in new data.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using net core with ViewModel, which required to post with "." as form values. I have below instead, hopefully this helps anyone came across something similar.

```
ajax: {
  url: "/api.json",
  data: function (d) {
   return $('form#filter').serialize() + "&" + $.param(d);
  }
 }
```